# Select top sold product from sales table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sales table with those rows:

[image: Sales table]

cd_produto is the product code and qtd_produto is the quantity of the product that has been sold(daaah)

I want to get the top sold products. In this case it would be product #1 since it sums to 8 (1+7).
The second would be #3 because it's 6.

If i run

```
SELECT TOP 3 cd_produto, qtd_produto FROM itens_vendas ORDER BY qtd_produto DESC
```

I'll get them by top sales. But it would not sum the qtd for each individual product. It would consider 1 as the top sold but only because it's value is 7, and it will ignore the 1.

How do i order them by the SUM of each product?

Comment: please tag the database you are using

Comment: Yeah i guess i forgot that, done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by` and get the `sum` and use it in `order by`.

```
SELECT TOP 3 cd_produto, 
sum(qtd_produto) 
FROM itens_vendas 
GROUP BY cd_produto
ORDER BY sum(qtd_produto) DESC
```

Edit:

```
SELECT TOP 3 i.cd_produto, 
p.productname, sum(i.qtd_produto)          
FROM itens_vendas i 
join producttable p on i.cd_produto = p.product_id
GROUP BY cd_produto
ORDER BY sum(qtd_produto) DESC
```

Comment: Yup. Beat me to it. ^

Comment: I would like to ask for something else.

Comment: I have the product name on another table, which has the product name and product code. How can i select the product names for those 3 ?

Comment: see the edited answer. You have to join that table. Change the table and column names to be appropriate.